# How to use Substring method in Blazor for Parent Child relation?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am Beginner at Blazor and have created a simple application in Blazor WASM. there is a parent-child relationship. What I have actually wanted is Parent should pass the FirstName that has been sliced and  Child Component should get the sliced FirstName as a parameter and it should be displayed on the page.

My Parent Component

```
@using BlSls.Client.Shared

        <Child FirstName="@FirstName" />

@code{

 
private string FirstName ="Royster" ;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
       FirstName=FirstName.SubString(0,FirstName.Length-4);
}

  

}
```

My Child component

```
<span >Welcome,@FirstName</span>
@code {

     [Parameter] public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

I need to display the FirstName called "Royster" as "Roy" on the page. But I couldn't get the sliced string to the child. Instead of that, I got the complete string. what is my wrong point?? can anybody help me?

Comment: No repro. This isn't happening. Also, SubString() does not exist. Post a real [mre].

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you are putting your substring code in  `OnInitializedAsync()` keep it in `OnInitialized()`

Also, your code can be improved:

ParentComponent:

```
@using BlSls.Client.Shared

<Child SlicedName="@SlicedName" />

@code{
private string FirstName ="Royster" ;
private string SlicedName;
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
       SlicedName=FirstName.SubString(0,FirstName.Length-3);
}
}
```

Since substring is not a particularly expensive operation, you can directly use it in parameter assignment:

```
@using BlSls.Client.Shared

<Child SlicedName="@FirstName.SubString(0,FirstName.Length-3)" />

@code{
private string FirstName ="Royster" ;
}
```

Comment: [Polite] It has nothing to do with OnInitialized()/OnInitializedAsync().  The code as shown doesn't run!  Also putting inline C# code blocks in Razor code may be efficient in lines of code, but it can soon get messy and very hard to read!

Comment: It's an individual preference. I personally prefer to put everything in code behind. But I guessed that the OP just wanted to try out a few things to work and get a 'look and feel' of blazor before deep diving. For individual coders that comes before the 'best practices' bit.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working version of your code.

1. The component is the same.
2. I've split out the firstName.
3. `SubString` is actually `Substring`, and doesn't work is the way you've coded it.
4. `OnInitializedAsync` has lost the `async` as there's no async behaviour.
5. I've put your method on the button click.

```
@page "/Hello"
<Child FirstName="@shortFirstName" />

<div class="m-3">
    <button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick="Calc">Your Calculation</button>
</div>
@code{

    private string FirstName = "Royster";
    private string shortFirstName = "Royster";

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        shortFirstName = FirstName.Substring(0, 3);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    protected void Calc()
        => shortFirstName = FirstName.Substring(0, FirstName.Length - 3);

}
```

What Dev. environment are you using?  Why aren't you getting compile errors?

Comment: When you fix Substring() then  the original code shows "Roys" in the Child. It's not clear what problem needs solving.

Comment: Agreed, my answer is simply corrections to the supplied code that works and compiles!  And the questioner did want "Roy".